# UnetStack : How to get an automatic transmission of data between two modems

Tags: groovy, unetstack

I have two subnero WNC-M25MSS3 modems, my goal is to realize a 2 nodes network. They are made of co-processor and Janus protocol.
During my future deployment at sea, the modem named A will be located on the surface and the modem B in depth, I could connect to the shell of the modem A in order to carry out the commands of the scripts which I created there. My goal is the following: I must requisition data from B when I enter the command line "requestData" in the shell of A. To do this, once the command line is entered, this will generate a Janus message with data inside which will be transmitted to B. When B receives the message, it should automatically respond with the data. This is where I get stuck, I have created the data transmission scripts for both modems, but I can't find a way to make B "listen", i.e. wait for the message from A, as soon as it receives it, transmit the data and then listen again.

Here is the function of modem A to call a transmission:

```
B = host('B');
subscribe phy; 
int counterA = 3; // counter which will create in the future

int ID = 0; // Transmitting to everybody 

int [] request = new int[2];

request[0] = counterA; // Data is create in a table
request[1] = ID;
// request[2] = ; ????

phy << new TxJanusFrameReq(type: CONTROL, data: request, to: ID); // Transmission of data with Janus
```

Here is the infinite loop that I created on modem B so that it transmits with "sendData" once a message is received: it is here that I get stuck

```
subscribe phy;

while(RxFrameNtf !=  true){
    //receivedData = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    //receivedData = ntf.data;
    try{
            
            try {      //wait 5 seconds function
                Thread.sleep(5000) ;
            }  catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // gestion de l'erreur
            }
            
            receivedData = ntf.data;  // Analyse the receiving data
            
        }catch (Exception e){
            //println([receivedData]);
            println("No data yet");
            //tampomEvent;
        }
        //println([receivedData]);
}
println("Amazing, you're out now!!!");


if(ntf.data[1] == 0){
    println("OK");
    sendData;
}
```

Comment: Can you try removing the `type: CONTROL` from the `TxJanusFrameReq` command and try? If you have not configured `phy[1]` as JANUS, the transmission may not be working. Once you do this, also check the `phy[3].frameLength` and make sure it is large enough to send the data you want.

This article explains some of these: https://blog.unetstack.net/converting-your-laptop-into-a-janus-modem-using-unetaudio

Comment: Do you have a specific requirement for JANUS? Since you're communicating between 2 Subnero modems, you'd get better performance by using the default schemes in the modem rather than switching to JANUS, which is designed for cross-vendor compatibility but not performance.